# using a method declared in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, blackberry-10

I am developing a BlackBerry 10 apps with Cascades in C++.
I'm just a beginner, and this problem really confused me.
I have a class `Parser` and a derived class `LicenseParser`.

```
Class Parser {
    // implementation
}
```

and

```
Class LicenseParser : public Parser {
    // ...
    public:
    void Parse();
}
```

In another file:

```
Parser* p= new LicenseParser();
p->Parse();
```

But I got an error:

```
class Parser' has no member named 'parse'
```

The method `Parse` is declared in the derived class so I know it can be used without declaring it in the `Parser` class!
How should I correct this?

Comment: Add virtual void parese() = 0; and you have an abstract base class, which can not be instantiated.

Comment: The code looks correct, but the error message implies you're trying to call `parse` not `Parse` - C++ is case sensitive. Are you sure you've posted the *exact* code and error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `p` is a pointer to a `Parser`, not a pointer to a `LicenseParser`.

Despite the fact the *you* know the `p` *actually* points to a `LicenseParser`, your assignment to a base class pointer means that you choose to not let the compiler know anything about it.

You should either have a virtual `Parse` member function in the base class, or have the variable `p` be a `LicenseParser*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think your capitalization is mismatched on `parse` vs `Parse`.  See if fixing that helps as C++ is case-sensitive. (*Note:  Looks like your edit fixed that after my original answer*)

Also, because `p` is declared as a `Parser*`, the compiler will flag an error because `Parse` is not defined in the `Parser` class.  Declare a pure `virtual` function `Parse` in `Parser` (e.g. `virtual void Parse() = 0;`) and it should compile (assuming `Parse` is defined in the .cpp file for `LicenseParser`).

You could also declare `p` as a `LicenseParser*` and so not need to declare the `virtual` function `Parse` in `Parser`

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

> "'class Parser' has no member named 'parse"

If this is what you get, I think you should change the capitalization. In the fist file you declare

```
void Parse();
```

while on the other you request

```
p->parse();
```